# Saving scraped data to mysql database through phantomjs and casperjs

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Hi I am working on a web scraper, first I was trying to scrape using php `CURL`, but then I faced a problem that I wasn't able to scrape the sites which loads through `AJAX` and then I shifted to 'phantom JS' and 'casper JS`.

Now I have successfully installed the webkit and can scrape the data from any website, but I am unable to save the data for long use in  a database. Simply, for later use. What I want to do is, whatever data I have scraped I want to save that to mySql database.

Is there any way I can achieve such functionality? I have tried sending `Ajax` request to send the data to the database but failed.

I came up with one another solution for instance, that is when I scrape the data from the specified website, I push the data to an array called `data[]` and then I write that data to a `.json` file. Where each bunch of data is saved in array of objects form which is get from `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Now, I don't know if how can I get that file data and save it in database? Is it possible that, whenever the scraping is finished, right after I grab data from that `.json` file and save it to database.

**For now just take this code as an example**

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
var file = require('fs');
var data = [];

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
  data.push(this.getTitle());
  file.write("file.json", JSON.stringify(data), "a");
});


casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution I found is to make ajax request to the server, inside the evaluate function :

```js
casper.then(function() {
  details = this.evaluate(function() {
    var elDet = document.getElementsByClassName("job-description-column")[0];
    var detLen = elDet.children[2].children[0].children.length;
    var details = elDet.children[2].children[0].children;
    var linkedData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < detLen; i++) {
      if (details[i].nodeName == "H3" && details[i].id != "if-this-sounds-like-you,-apply") {
        linkedData.push({
          head: details[i].textContent,
          description: details[i + 1].textContent,
          title: elDet.children[0].children[0].children[0].textContent,
          loc: elDet.children[0].children[0].children[1].textContent,
          date: elDet.children[0].children[0].children[2].textContent
        })
        i++;
      } else {
        linkedData.push({
          head: "No Head",
          description: details[i].textContent,
          title: elDet.children[0].children[0].children[0].textContent,
          loc: elDet.children[0].children[0].children[1].textContent,
          date: elDet.children[0].children[0].children[2].textContent
        })
      }
    }
    var s = JSON.stringify(linkedData);
    console.log(linkedData);
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/fiverr/Crawl%20The%20Jobs/modal_scripts.php",
      data: "add_jobdets=true&job_details=" + s,
      async: false
    })
    return linkedData;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A Proof Of Concept, using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
#!/bin/bash

casperjs script.js
[[ -s file.json ]] || exit 1
jq '"UPDATE ROW SET XXX = "+ .[] + " WHERE FOO=BAR;"' file.json | mysql -D DB_name
```

---

The file.json :

```
[
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "base" 
]
```

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) output :

```
jq -r '"UPDATE ROW SET XXX = "+ .[] + " WHERE FOO=BAR;"' file.json
```

```
UPDATE ROW SET XXX = foo WHERE FOO=BAR;
UPDATE ROW SET XXX = bar WHERE FOO=BAR;
UPDATE ROW SET XXX = base WHERE FOO=BAR;
```

Check https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: what is `jq` @Gilles ?

Comment: can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945281/saving-table-data-obtained-while-scrapping-a-webpage-using-casperjs) solve my problem ?